# CakePHP 4 JSON column values find or set aliases

Tags: php, mysql, json, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

So I noticed in the CakePHP 4 documentation their isnt a way to use find on JSON field values in a JSON mySQL column. Every time i try to explain what I'm doing it seems to get lost somewhere in translation so I'll explain what I need to happen:

Find entries based on a JSON column value. So in my table i have a json column named "additional_info", inside "additional_info" there are multiple json field values, for example: {1:{org_id:"",name:"", etc. In order to find what i need, i need to be able to set a condition based on the json field values org_id; if i set a condition with addition_info.org_id = 1, show all the records where 1 is located in the tables json column.

I have been stuck on this for multiple days and haven't found a good way to accomplish this. I have messed with the beforeFind in the model, behaviors, traits and collections. I believe my problem is solved with one of the methods i was messing with, but if not any examples on this would be much appreciated!

If able, i would like this to be set in the table model, as to make the change global.(i am not concerned with this)

Comment: Why don't you make `org_id` a normal column?

Comment: I’m modifying a table that was already created and has thousands of records set. That option isn’t exactly feasible atm.

Comment: I’m hoping there’s a way to set aliases and set that alias to the specific value I’m looking for.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/liqueurdetoile/cakephp-orm-json

Comment: MySQL v.5.6.43 - @waspinator that plugin is not supported on cakephp 4 along with the most recent update done not being successful. Is there a more stable alternative plugin?

Comment: sorry I lied. MySQL v.5.7.31. @Salines

Comment: At this point it looks like an example of modifying the SQL statement in beforeFind using JSON_EXTRACT() would be the best way to go about it. Does anyone have an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's learn how to select field as alias:

**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data**

```
// Results in SELECT id AS pk, title AS aliased_title, body ...
$query = $articles->find();
$query->select(['pk' => 'id', 'aliased_title' => 'title', 'body']);
```

> So in my table i have a json column named "additional_info", inside
> "additional_info" there are multiple json field values

```
// $additional_info = {
//    1:{
//        org_id:"",
//        name:""
//    }};
```

> At this point it looks like an example of modifying the SQL statement in beforeFind using JSON_EXTRACT() would be the best way to go about it. Does anyone have an example of this?

```
// SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_info, $.[1].org_id)) AS org_id

$query->select(['org_id' => 'JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_info, $.[1].org_id))'])
```

Where:

```
// .. WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_info, $.[1].org_id)) = `1`

$query->where(['JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_info, $.[1].org_id))' => '1'])
```

To reuse your code, you can **create custom finder**

**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods**

in Behavior

**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors.html#creating-a-behavior**

Comment: I'm using cake4 and had to use it like `->where([ 'JSON_EXTRACT(payload, "$.is_active") = true']);`, because if would have otherwise used `->where([JSON_EXTRACT(payload, "$.is_active") = true])` it would generate a SQL like `JSON_EXTRACT(payload, "$.is_echtdorsten") '1')`.